# meta-qt- yocto layer- change default qt platform (QT_QPA_PLATFORM)

Tags: qt, qt5, yocto, bitbake

I'm using Yocto buildsystem to create an image for raspberry pi that contains Qt5, but I'm having problems with configuring qtbase properly.
Due to those problems when I run Qt app I get an error:

```
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "".

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen.

Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

On the other hand if I start my app like so:

```
myApp -platform eglfs
```

it works properly. The same if I set environment variable `QT_QPA_PLATFORM=eglfs` - it works.

How can I set my default platform to `eglfs` and not to `xcb`?

I have tried to set it like below (in my distro.conf):

```
DISTRO_FEATURES_remove = "x11"
DISTRO_FEATURES_append = " gles2"
PACKAGECONFIG_GL_pn-qtbase = "gles2"
PACKAGECONFIG_X11_pn-qtbase = ""
PACKAGECONFIG_pn-qtbase += "gles2"
PACKAGECONFIG_pn-qtbase += "dbus udev evdev widgets tools libs"
```

Unfortunately it did not help and my application still shows this error if I don't set platform explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

all you have to do is:

in `/etc/profile`, add

`export QT_QPA_PLATFORM=eglfs` so that every time you logged in the machine, it will automatically does it for you.

Or if you do not know what your graphic backends is.  The following is the corresponding

Backend: FB; XWayland; X11

GRAPHICS: eglfs; wayland-egl; xcb

`export QT_QPA_PLATFORM=${GRAPHICS}`

Comment: I have already found that it can be change by passing `-qpa eglfs` to qtbase `configure` script, but thank you- this is also helpful (especially for testing other platforms)

Comment: To elaborate on the above, add ```QT_CONFIG_FLAGS += " -qpa eglfs"``` to ```local.conf``` (in my case I wanted to set the default to linxfb, so I added ```QT_CONFIG_FLAGS += " -qpa linuxfb"```).